# How to parse user input from console separated by minus sign

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If user inputs `file1-file2` from console. I need to copy all code from `file1` to `file2`.

How do I parse this syntax? I know how to do it if user inputs `file1` and then `file2`, but not `file1-file2`

Comment: I do not understand. User creates a file with a long filename, and you should split filename in two components, and each file should have same content? Maybe if you add an example of what you have and what you want, this could help us understanding your question

Comment: No. I have file1 which already exist. Then I need to copy all content from file1 to file2. User can input 'file1-qwertyzxc' and all content from file1 will be copied to qwertyzxc. I need to realease it with '-' symbol and the command should be inline

Comment: Ok. When you precise your question, you should edit the question, and maybe just notify in comment (and tag the relevant people) that you edited the question. I hope someone will answer you. My solution is ugly (`eval sed ...`), whete sed split the initial argument in two component, and also prepare the command to be executed by eval. Ugly. I hope there are much better answers

Comment: I thought about split the string by '-' symbol and then copy content from string1 to string2. I think I just try this solution. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting field separtor to `-` and read user input:

```sh
IFS=- read a b # user inputs 'file1-file2' here
echo "$a" # file1
echo "$b" # file2
```

Comment: Already did it like this but with array. Your solution more elegant. Thx.